# React ES6 importing a stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have been searching for the answer to this forever lol.  How can I import a stateless react class into another class? I am getting the error:

"warning.js:45Warning: HTMLImageElement(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`, returned null/false from a stateless component, or tried to render an element whose type is a function that isn't a React component."

I am trying to import the CalloutImage component....

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class CalloutImage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Image onClick={this.handleClick} className="header-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453106037972-08fbfe790762?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=cbaaa89f2c5394ff276ac2ccbfffd4a4" />
        )
    }
    handleClick() {
        alert();
    }

}
```

into ....

```
import { CalloutImage } from './CalloutImage.jsx'

const lorem = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navigation />
                <Grid>
                    <CalloutImage />
                    <ColumnContent />
                </Grid>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        ) 
    }
}

class Navigation extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar inverse>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>VA</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav>
                        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Home</NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">About</NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#">Users</NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}

class ColumnContent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Row>
                <Col sm={6}>
                    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                    <p>{lorem}</p>
                </Col>
                <Col sm={6}>
                    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                    <p>{lorem}</p>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}




class Footer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <footer>
                <Grid>
                    <p>VA &copy;</p>
                </Grid>
            </footer>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: try this `import  CalloutImage  from './CalloutImage.jsx'` in case your CalloutImage.jsx just returns one component.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri this won't work because `CalloutImage` is a regular export, not the `default` export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Image` should be lowercase, otherwise React thinks it's a React component and tries to call `render()` on it.

Comment: lol wait you have to be kidding me.  I'm also using react-bootstrap and they have an Image component i was using, so wouldn't it have to be uppercase?

Comment: If that's what you're using, be sure to import the component.

Answer (score 0):

In React JSX, if you are using `HTML tags`, then it should be `lowercase`. For all other user-defined or any other imported components from external packages should always be `Capitalized`.

In your code, since you are using `<Image />` component from `react-bootstrap` you should import that component into your file and then use it.